# Filter products by stock availability. Opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Initially I'm sorry for my english.

There is a task to filter products in a category depending on the availability of a promotion (special products). I found a suitable module - "product filter by availability" and am trying to adapt it to the current task.

In the model, instead of:

```
$sql .= " AND (p.stock_status_id = '6' OR p.quantity > 0)";
```

I've written

```
$sql .= " AND (ps.product_id = '*')";
```

But an error occurs that there is no such table in the query results (

So, in the model I add:

```
"LEFT 
 JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps 
   ON (p.product_id = ps.product_id)"
```

i.e. instead of this

```
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";
```

we get

```
  $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps ON (p.product_id = ps.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";
```

But I still get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: Unknown column 'ps.product_id' in 'where clause'<br />Error No: 1054<br />SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM oc_review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special FROM oc_product_to_category p2c LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LE in /opt/lampp/htdocs/oc3_tst/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 40
```

But in this case, the "oc_product_special" table is already present in the error text ...

Already perverted even so:

```
      if (!empty($data['filter_instock'])) {
       $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductSpecials();
         if ($results) {
           foreach ($results as $result) {
         $sql .= " AND (p.product_id = '" . $result['product_id'] . "')";
      }
    }
   }
```

Displays special item only if there is only one))

May you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm inserting a JOIN in the wrong place? Or is it even easier to do it with a controller?

Here is a module in the file that I adapted for opencart 3 (originally it was for the 2nd version)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mLlmZuB76hoBVbyk3RmxnJJaRFXN34s1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: We could try to figure out what's wrong, but it might be easier to simply start over, with a sample dataset and a desired result.

Comment: So, decision was:

        if (!empty($data['filter_instock'])) {
            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductSpecials();
 
            $id_products = array();
 
            if ($results) {
                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    $id_products[] = $result['product_id'];
                }
            }
 
            if (!empty($id_products)) {
                $sql .= " AND p.product_id IN (" . implode(',', $id_products) . ")";
            }
        }